# What is a more descriptive name for an event organized in the following way. I am sure it is not a webinar, although it was called that.

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a good descriptive name for an event organized in the following way.

1. The participants are sent a YouTube link to a video containing a commented slideshow.
2. They watch the video in their leisure time.
3. A week after that, there is a face-to-face moderated discussion on the topic of the video lecture.

It is not a webinar, it is not a webcast. What is it?

Comment: Well, 1. and 2. don't represent a single "organized event" because they're done independently and at disparate times. There may be a name for 3., but I'm not sure it would be any more specific or descriptive than your "moderated discussion". In other words, you may be on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Well, since "webinar" is an invented term, you can invent your own if you wish -- "youtubeushion" perhaps.

Comment: @HotLicks Or "**webture**": web + lecture.

Answer (score 2):

> 3. A week after that, there is a face-to-face moderated discussion on the
>      topic of the video lecture.

This could be called a "**discussion group**" if it occurs with the same participants more than once. In the olden days (ie before YouTube), this is very similar in structure to a **Book Club** where people were expected to read a certain book before each face-to-face gathering where the book was discussed.

If this is a one-time occurrence (with these particular participants) then its called a **seminar**.

Answer (score 0):

If the participants were school children, I'd call it a "**flipped classroom**".